# Convert html code into ruby on rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new in rails. I have written some code in html :

```
<textarea onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',160);" id="message" style="WIDTH: 608px; HEIGHT: 94px">
</textarea>
<input disabled  maxlength="3" size="3" value="160" id="counter">
```

Now i want to do the same thing in rails. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of the question is :

```
<%= text_area 'message', 'message_text', :onkeyup => "textCounter(this,'counter',160);", :width => 30 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<%= text_area_tag :comment, :text, size: "20x30", :id => "message", onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',160);") %>

<%= text_field_tag :create_text), :id => "counter", :value => 160, :disabled=>true, :input_html => {:maxlength => 3, :size => 3}  %>
```